# Forcing MPI to use a specified no. of cores

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmpi

I am kinda new to MPI, so forgive me if it is a trivial question. I have a quad core CPU. And I want to run an OpenMPI C++ program that uses two processes on a single core. Is there any way to do so? If so, then how? I referred to [this link on stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5797615/mpi-cores-or-processors) which, *most probably*, says that there *might* be a way... If so, then how can I do it?

Comment: For clarification: you are trying to run a MPI program with 2 MPI processes on your 4-core machine, and want both processes to run only on a single core?

Comment: @Patrick : Yes, I want both of my programs to run a single core thereby overriding the default optimization provided by MPI

Comment: What operating system are you running on?

Comment: @Patrick: I am using Ubuntu 12.04 LTS as my OS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since MPI spawns separate processes, the scheduling of processes onto cores is generally/usually performed by your operating system. You can still achieve what you want by manually setting the affinity of the processes to a specific core.

You can do this in Linux using the `sched_setaffinity` function.

To *pin* a process to a specific core, you can use the following approach:

```c
#include <mpi.h>
#include <sched.h>

// ...

void pin_to_core(int cpuid) {                                            
    cpu_set_t set;                                                       
    CPU_ZERO(&set);                                                      
    CPU_SET(cpuid,&set);                                                                                                                                                                                                         
    sched_setaffinity(0,sizeof(cpu_set_t),&set);
}

// ....

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    pin_to_core(0); // pin process to core 0
    // ...
    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Make sure to call this function *after* you call `MPI_Init` in your `main` function and specify the core you want to *pin* the process to.

Comment: Open MPI (and in fact every major MPI implementation out there) has a built-in **portable** mechanism to specify process binding/pinning.

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to implement this with Open MPI is to provide a *rankfile* which tells the library where to place each process. The following rankfile should suffice in your case:

```
rank 0=localhost slot=0
rank 1=localhost slot=0
```

It tells Open MPI that both ranks should run on the local host and be bound to OS CPU 0, which is usually the first core. Provide the rankfile *in addition* to the hostfile or the host list:

```
$ mpiexec --host localhost --report-bindings --rankfile ./rankfile -np 2 hostname
[cluster:03247] MCW rank 0 bound to socket 0[core 0]: [B . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .] (slot list 0)
[cluster:03247] MCW rank 1 bound to socket 0[core 0]: [B . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .][. . . . . . . .] (slot list 0)
cluster
cluster
```